# Как сделать всплывающие окна в QT?

Tags: c++, qt, виджет

Как сделать, чтобы по нажатию кнопки открывалось новое окно, которое может содержать ещё кнопки и поля для ввода?

Я нашёл в интернете, что можно использовать `QStackedWidget`, но не нашёл по нему информации. Есть ли какая-нибудь команда или библиотека для этого или нужно создавать своё подобие `QMessangeBox`?

Comment: вы серьёзно это пишете или такой прикол?

Comment: Вы про вопрос или комментарий?

Comment: нет я про `Я нашёл в интернете, что можно использовать QStackedWidget, но не нашёл по нему информации`

Comment: Вопрос очень плохой. Вместо того, чтобы почитать по учебникам, по help о QDialog, посмотреть примеры что можно сделать, вы сразу же пишете на SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавляете к проекту новый "qt"->"класс формы qt designer" (например, mydialog)
В mainwindow.h добавляете заголовок

```
#include "mydialog.h"
```

и где понадобится создаете и показываете диалог

```
mydialog* dlg = new mydialog();
mydialog->exec();
```